# Go cgo - ignore C source files on windows

Tags: go, cgo

I have a lib, that uses some C on linux. On windows it is just a dummy noop lib with functions that do nothing.

The lib is in 3 files: `lib_linux.go`, `lib_win.go` and `lib.c`

But when I try to compile it on windows, it throws this error: `C source files not allowed when not using cgo or SWIG: lib.c`

How can I tell to the go compiler to ignore the C source files on windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [similar issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/9132) suggests (when tailored to your case):

> ### workarounds
>
> - Rename the `.c` file lib_linux.c;
> - Or add a [build constraint](https://pkg.go.dev/go/build#hdr-Build_Constraints) `// +build linux` condition to the top of the `.c` file ([conditional compilation](https://dave.cheney.net/2013/10/12/how-to-use-conditional-compilation-with-the-go-build-tool)).

Comment: that's great, I didn't know, that the `_linux.c` suffix does something and also that `// +build linux` can be added to a c file.